# I can't get a unittest to run (Python)

Tags: unit-testing, python-unittest

```
import unittest
from github_repos import get_response

class GHTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        print("Hello")

    def setUp(self):
        self.languages = ['pyTHon', 'c', 'C#', 'Ruby', 'lua']
        print("Hey there!")

    def api_call(self):
        print(":'(")
        for language in self.languages:
            response = self.get_response(language)
            self.assertTrue(len(response) == 30)

unittest.main()
```

Got this unittest here, and for some reason it would seem like the test doesn't even initialize. It just says that it run zero test, and even when I try to add an `__init__` function with a print statement, it still doesn't print a thing, just say that 0 tests were run. I don't get why this happens, I wrote another unittest for another program, it was pretty much like this one, and it worked. Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Well, you don't have a test function here. Note that a test function name should start with `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're supposed to run unittest with something like `python3 -m unittest Basic_Test.Testing`. How are you running your code? You could always try running the other unittest the way you're running this one.

Comment: I run the .py file containing this code with my IDE, the same way I ran all my other unit tests, and it always worked up until now.

Comment: @OlegShevchenko Can you try actually running an older unittest?

Comment: Yeah, and the other ones are still working, but this one doesn't.